# Authentication Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When the dispatch method `Auth::attempt` and `Auth::check` returns `true` and then redirect to the Route `admin`

```
class LoginController extends Controller {

    public function login(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        if (Auth::attempt($request->only(['login', 'password']))) {
            var_dump(Auth::check()); // true
            return redirect()->intended('admin');
        }

        return back();
    }
}
```

Route `admin` have middleware

```
class AdminMiddleware
    {
        public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        {
            var_dump(Auth::check()); // false

            if (!Auth::check()) {
                return view('login');
            }

            return $next($request);
        }
    }
```

And then redirect method `Auth :: check` returns`false`, why is this happening?

Comment: It could be a session issue, check if your cookie settings are set up correctly.

Comment: what settings specifically ? config -> session ?

Comment: make sure your admin middleware comes after the `web` group middleware as the session initialized there.

Comment: Thank, but now another problem 
`FatalErrorException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 135:
Call to a member function setCookie() on a non-object`

Comment: @KhoteyVitaliy use tags otherwise I cant see that you posted,anyway thats not really helpful,have you checked which line causing this ? is it comming from admin middleware?

Comment: Yes, config -> session. You can check your browser developer console to see if cookies are set properly.

Answer (score 0):

replace your code with:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Closure;
use Auth;

class AdminMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!Auth::check()) {
            return new Response(view('login'));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use a `try this` as your answer. Good answer should provide an explanation about problem and solution. If you are sure that your answer is correct then is no need to use `try this` but simply `do this becasue` or `replace your code with`. If you are not sure then use comment instead of answer.